# How does spinning up a node within a cluster reduce CPU load?

Tags: monitoring, cluster, docker, vagrant, containers

I have a VM (representing a baremetal server) with a load balancer and a cluster of 3 container nodes that requests distribute to.

Say some threshold is hit and I scale up a 4th node in the cluster. Clearly, more requests can be processed, but does this decrease the CPU load of the baremetal?

If so, what metrics should I monitor to determine the need to scale a 4th node.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is all happening on your one virtual machine, so no, if anything adding more nodes will increase the CPU load.

The idea behind this kind of scaling is to spread out the load across multiple physical servers.  If you only have one server to do it on, you aren't helping much by adding more nodes.

Setting up this kind of environment on a single machine is fine for learning and development, but to do any kind of performance testing you need multiple physical servers to scale across.

Comment: Ok, that's the answer I was expecting to hear. Thanks. CPU aside, would increasing nodes in a cluster allow for more requests to be handled?

Comment: @coderkid it depends.  If each node is configured with limited resources, yes, you'd be able to handle more.  If there are no restrictions, for most applications you'd get better performance having a single properly tuned container handling requests.